# SharedObject Data Overwriting Wrong Information

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, shared-objects

I'm working on a system that lets users input names and numbers. That information is stored in a sharedobject called "so". I've encountered an issue that when a user saves the information, it overwrites the correct piece of information AND all other so.data. I'm a bit lost here.

```
    function setInformation (name:String):Function{

      return function(e:Event):void {
          if (name == "1"){
             so.data.Number1 = editPage.enterNumber.text;
             so.data.Name1 = editPage.enterName.text;
             Name1.text = so.data.Name1;
             number1.text = so.data.Number1;
             editPage.setInfo.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, setInformation('1'));
             removePage();
          }
          if (name == "2"){
             so.data.Number2 = editPage.enterNumber.text;
             so.data.Name2 = editPage.enterName.text;
             Name2.text = so.data.Name2;
             number2.text = so.data.Number2;
             edit2.visible = false;
             delete2.visible = false;
             trace("HELLO THERE");
             editPage.setInfo.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, setInformation('2'));
             removePage();
          }
          if (name == "3"){
             so.data.Number3 = editPage.enterNumber.text;
             so.data.Name3 = editPage.enterName.text;
             Name3.text = so.data.Name3;
             number3.text = so.data.Number3;
             edit3.visible = false;
             delete3.visible = false;
             editPage.setInfo.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, setInformation('3'));
             removePage();
             displayNumbers();
          }
      }
    }
```

The main function is activated by multiple event listeners that declare a name, for example:

```
 editPage.setInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, setInformation('1'));
```

That enables the *"if (name == '1')"* conditional. I think this system might be affecting my issue but I can't see why or what is causing it.

Comment: I think that part of the problem may be that you're, in essence, using lambas (anonymous functions) for your event listeners. This means that there's no actual way to remove the event listener once it's been added.

Are you able to post more of your code to show _why_ you need to have it set up this way?

Comment: Is this the only part of your code that affects your shared object? The part looks correct except for the anonymous function bit which might not get removed properly. To check for removal, use `hasEventListener` function result like this: `trace(editPage.setInfo.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));` Place this statement after your listener removal statement and check if the result is false. If it's true, you have to abandon lambda function, and instead write several similar functions (or make an array and use `return functionsArray[0]` syntax for your lambda).